# Is there a Card Cap?

Tags: hearthstone

I haven't dusted any of my duplicate cards in a while. I have quite a few common cards that show a count of "9+".

Is there a maximum number of copies of a card? What happens when I hit that maximum, is the card auto-dusted or is it just lost?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As there is not offical statement on the card limits, at worst there would be some programming related limit.

**At the very worst** this number of cards would be stored in and *signed 8-bit number variable*, putting the maximum number of cards at 127.

Most likely the number is at *least* 8-bit *unsigned* integer (because you can't have negative amount of cards), putting the maximum at **255**.

16-bit integer is also possible, when the maximum would be 32,767 or 65,535 (depending on wether the number is signed or not). But then Blizzard would need double the space to store people's collections.

In short, unless you think you have literaly hundreds of copies of a given card, you shouldn't have to worry.

(Assuming Blizzard isn't doing something incredibly fancy trickery, but that would be impossible to speculate any limits on.)

Comment: As an aside, Blizzard uses (or at least, originally used) signed 32 bit integers for card attack and health values. It's possible that they used the same data type for card counts.

Comment: @twobugs I sort of doubt this. For attack and health, they only need to store these values once per card *type* and temporarily for the match. But for card collections they would need to store a number for *each card type* for *each user* in some sort of database. I doubt they'd use anything above 16 bits, as that would increase the size of this (no doubt huge) database (literaly) exponentialy. And all they would benefit would be to be able to store values above 30 thousand. Maybe ease of coding, maybe.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. Lets say they are prepared for 200 million users (current number is about 75 million) and 1000 cards (currently about 500?). If the number of cards is stored in 32 bits, the database would be about 1 terabyte, including some space for overhead. This is *peanuts*, when it comes to databases, for a company like Blizzard.

Comment: Yeah, ints don't take up enough space to be worrying about database size for storing that alone. Plus they'd probably have separate databases for each regional server, because why would you not. (Come to think of it, there's not a lot else to store--9 standard decks per player, 1 arena deck, 1 tavern brawl deck. Hearthstone must be really cheap storage-wise for Blizzard.)

Comment: I would bet money that these are stored in a 32 bit, or even 64 bit, integer. Storage is incredibly cheap, changing schema and assumptions is not.

Comment: on the other hand why should it be presented as 9+ if it isnt limited by even 999, if we are speculating that way.

Comment: @Zaibis I'd take that more as a gentle nudge towards "You know, you don't really *need* this many of these. As in, ever. At all."

Comment: Take it as "don't argue to them that it COULD be, if they can't realize how stupid it would be programmatically to take anything else as unsigned char. Even the person that has 255 cards wouldn't notice loosing cards of that type without getting dust. ;)

Comment: @Zaibis "9+" is two characters long.  By fixing the length of displayed characters, some layout assumptions can be made in the UI.

Comment: @DavidB: Yeah but I wasn't talking about the ui representation but about the serverside datastorage of the count information.

Answer (score 8):

No. I've seen plenty of streamers getting 9+ cards and they've kept opening cards.

Blizzard hasn't mentioned anything about a card cap either, so you're safe.

Comment: There is likely a (realistically unreachable) cap at the limit of the data type they use to represent it. This would likely be 2^31, 2^32, 2^63 or 2^64 (minus one, since the zero is included), depending on if they use signed/unsigned int/long... OR it could be something totally different. Anyway, your answer covers all realistic situations, +1.

Comment: Just because Blizzard hasn't mentioned a card cap (you know of) doesn't mean that there is none.

Comment: That is true, however, it most likely means that there is not a limit that is reachable in the near future.

Comment: We thought that Steam Monster Summer Game didn't have a limit. And guess what, 100m. But yeah, john is correct.