# Hearthstone Pack Opening Interuption

Tags: hearthstone

So I was opening a classic pack in Hearthstone.

1. I dragged the pack to the center of the screen to bust it open
2. I got invited to Brawl a friend
3. I accepted the invitation without clicking on any of the cards
4. After the Brawl I went back to click on my cards, but they were gone
5. When I checked my collection there were no new cards listed.

Obviously I could have just gotten duplicate cards, but it has me a little concerned. Did I get duplicates or did I just lose the pack :O

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably a bug and should be discussed with the developers, and not on Arqade.

Comment: @ardaozkal not necessarily a bug, other players on arqade may have encountered the same thing, but noticed if they received duplicates or new cards. although it's an unlikely scenario that OP is in, and even unliklier that someone in that scenario would be able to tell if the received duplicate cards

Comment: @ardaozkal Yeah i was hoping someone had had the same thing happen and could tell me if their cards got revealed and stuffed in their collection for them.

Comment: Do you frequently auto-dust your duplicates?  If so, you may be able to tell from the amount of dust you would receive from auto-dusting if you received the cards or not.

Comment: @MikeR Saddly... no: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235327/is-there-a-card-cap maybe this will teach me to though.

Comment: @MikeR I [did validate this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/251959/53654) after cleaning up card counts enough to see what happened as you suggested. This is in fact *not* a bug, and I am confident that I got cards when the question was asked as well.

Comment: Good to hear that.  I had suspected that would happen (based on similar behavior when the phone version crashes right after completing a game) but could only speculate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cards are opened as soon as you open the pack; you do not need to click on the cards to open them and 'send' them to your card collection.

Cards do not show as new if you have 2 or more of them, so it is likely you got 5 duplicates and they are hidden away in your deck somewhere.

http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/17086419786

Comment: LOL, we posted an answer at exactly the same time a day after the question had been posted. There should be some kind of Jinx badge for that. Anyway, [I obviously agree with your answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/251959/53654), sans the instruction to dust the cards upon acquiring more than 2. Could you [look at this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/165070/53654) and see if you agree?

Comment: Hmmm, that's very interesting to know actually. I would say it was scenario dependent then, seeing as though there's no card cap as per your other link. Like he said, it's difficult to predict the future of nerfs/ or changes... maybe on new expansions but other than that cards don't really get nerfed unless they're being used way more often and giving too large an advantage in championship.league play. Tough one...

Comment: @Downvoter Can I get some clarification as to what was wrong with this answer? I was going to accept it as it links proof of someone with my exact problem and the result. Seemed helpful enough that I was going to accept it.

Comment: @JonathanMee Indeed, I just stated the exact same thing as yourself. I dislike when people downvote with no reasons doesn't help me with improving answers and really doesn't help newbies get rep.

Answer (score 8):

So I retested this last night.

1. I got my card counts to where I could see the increase even if I got a duplicate
2. Busted open a pack
3. Accepted an invitation from a friend before opening the pack
4. Went back to the pack opening screen after completing a game with my friend, the cards were again gone
5. Checked my collection

I did have 5 new cards; so I must have got 5 duplicates last time too.